# using Apple's MKDirections to get ideal travel/traffic times

Tags: ios7, mapkit

I'm a little confused with the docs.  I saw that MKETAResponse.expectedTravelTime returns the time it would take under ideal conditions.  how do you get the travel time under current traffic conditions?

And if it actually does return travel time under traffic conditions, how do i get back the travel time under ideal conditions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought `expectedTravelTime` will always return time under actual travel conditions and the question is what is ideal travel conditions? There is no such a property on `MKDirectionsRequest` class and to obtain expected time without congestion I would try setting the `arrivalDate` or `departureDate` property on the request to some night hours and compare results.

Comment: I too thought that `expectedTravelTime` was under travel conditions but according to the docs: "This expected travel time reflects the time it takes to traverse the route under ideal conditions. The actual amount of time may vary based on traffic, weather, and other travel conditions."  .. it says "under ideal conditions".  That's where i got confused.  But when I do run the code with expectedTravelTime it's with traffic.  I'm sure there's a call to get it.  Just not sure where.